# Read CSV file escaping more than one character in Mulesoft

Tags: csv, escaping, mule, dataweave

I have a CSV file with a header and these values:

```
"20000160";"20000160";"177204930";"Zusammendruck ""Blumen"" nk 01.03.07";"2021";"01";"EUR";"599.000";"599,000";"599.00";"599,00 EUR";"EUR";"0.00";"0,00 EUR";"0.00";"0,00 EUR";"EUR"
"20000000";"20000000";"1013";"Einschreiben";"2021";"01";"EUR";"0.000";"0,000";"22.80";"22,80 EUR";"EUR";"0.00";"0,00 EUR";"0.00";"0,00 EUR";"EUR"
"20000000";"20000000";"1018";"Rückschein";"2021";"01";"EUR";"0.000";"0,000";"6.60";"6,60 EUR";"EUR";"0.00";"0,00 EUR";"0.00";"0,00 EUR";"EUR"
"8003325905";"8003325905";"233800118";"Prof.Services: Datenmanagement;Pauschale";"2021";"01";"EUR";"0.000";"0,000";"600.00";"600,00 EUR";"EUR";"0.00";"0,00 EUR";"108.00";"108,00 EUR";"EUR"
```

I configured File Read connector to escape `"Zusammendruck ""Blumen"" nk 01.03.07"`, and it is working:

```
<file:read doc:name="Read CSV, Set MIME Type" doc:id="bb378f83-d0ea-4951-8253-8253953ed9e7" path="${outputCSV}" outputMimeType='application/csv; streaming=true; quote="\""; separator=";"; escape="\""' outputEncoding="UTF-8" />
```

But I also have to escape `;` to correctly parse `"Prof.Services: Datenmanagement;Pauschale"`. I tried to configure the pattern as `escape="\"|;"` but I got an warn:

> WARN  2021-12-20 16:59:34,604 [[MuleRuntime].uber.26:
> [test].upload.BLOCKING @27454a45] [processor: ; event:
> eb625e31-61b5-11ec-a30d-00090ffe0001]
> org.mule.weave.v2.model.service.DefaultLoggingService$: Option
> `escape="|;` expects a value of length `1` but got `"|;`. Only the
> first character is going to be used and the rest is going to be
> ignored.

How can I read and parse data correctly, considering the example data?

Comment: On which version of Mule are you trying it? And is there a monthly patch applied on top of the base version?

Comment: it is just mule 4.4.0, no patches

Answer (score 0):

The default CSV parser in DataWeave has some limitations. For this reason I have developed a Mule module based on Apache Commons CSV. You can find it on GitHub: https://github.com/rbutenuth/csv-module The dependency is available on Maven Central, so you don't need to compile it yourself.

It can parse your CSV with the following settings:

```
<csv:config name="Csv_Config" doc:name="Csv Config" recordSeparator="\n" withHeaderLine="false" escape="">
    <csv:columns >
        <csv:column columnName="column_01" type="TEXT" />
        <csv:column columnName="column_02" type="TEXT" />
        <!-- columnss 3 to 16 ommitted -->
        <csv:column columnName="column_17" type="TEXT" />
    </csv:columns>
</csv:config>
```

I have used column_01 to column_17 as column names, as I could not guess meaningfull names from the content.

You **can** achieve it in your case with DataWeave with the following settings:

```
application/csv separator=";",quoteValues=true,quote="\"",escape="\""
```

Comment: Roger, thanks for your response! I tried to use it but I got: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The prefix "csv" for element "csv:config" is not bound.
can you help me on this?

Comment: Have you done the following steps:
1. Add dependency to pom.xml (see README.md on the github page)
2. Drag a csv-component onto the canvas of your application (this adds the namespace in the xml).
3. Switch to xml view, copy the xml from the answer into your xml
4. After that, you can delete the operation from step 2.

Comment: Alright Roger, I missed the step 2. But why should I delete the operation? How am I suppose to read it? Using the file:read connector? Really sorry, but I tried to use the Parse component but it is not working here. If you can please share your test flow, I should really appreciate it as your answer is very promising.

Comment: Step 2 add a dummy operation, but has the side effect the namespace is added to the XML. You can either edit the added operation, or remove it and copy the XML from my answer.